# "I'm done" or "I've done"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

When someone asks whether you have completed a task e.g. shopping, dinner. What should be your answer?

> I am done.

or

> I have done.

To me, the former sentence's formation, Sub + VBe+ Past Participle, falls to passive voice. Therefore, it has a totally different meaning from *I have done* Sub + Predicate (verb intransitive).

Addendum:

According to Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary 3rd ed., the verb *do* is an intransitive verb in the meaning of complete/finish.

In the sentence, same formation as *I am done*:

> I am beautiful.

The verb *am* (of VBe) links the adj *beautiful* to the subject of the sentence *I*. Therefore I, the subject of the sentence, is beautiful (in other words, state of being).

Then in the sentence :

> I am done.

The subject, *I*, is linked to the adjective *done*. So the subject's state of being is *done*, in other words *dead*?

Comment: "I have done" sounds rather archaic to me, largely because of John Donne's "When Thou hast done Thou hast not done, for I have more." But it's entirely possible that it's Donne's nationality rather than his epoch that accounts for his usage.

Answer (score 15):

*Done* is used as the past participle in combination with *have*, obviously, but *done* is also used as an adjective meaning "carried out, completed, or treated in a particular way: *her hunting days were done*" (Webster's); as such, either statement is correct depending on the context. Usually, "I have done" would require an object (done *what*, precisely?) and "I am done" would signify that one was finished with, say, a task. At least in the U.S., a person would be much more likely to say "I'm done" to indicate the conclusion of an activity like homework or chores, and so on.

Comment: I have heard _I am done_ mostly in the USA. To my hears, it would have a different meaning, but that is because my first language is Italian (see what _sono finito_ would mean in Italian). **:-)**

Comment: This does seem to be a UK vs. US English thing - I am in the US and "I have done" with no object sounds very strange to me (I've specifically noticed it in some British movies, actually).

Comment: Based on Webster's defination in the sentence : I am done ; I , the subject of sentece , is being completed. It's not the task which is completed.

Comment: *I have done* without an object sounds outright incorrect to my (American) ears. You can say *I have finished* if you don't like "I'm done" for whatever reason (whyever not?), but **not** "I have done".

Answer (score 5):

'Have' is strictly correct. You would properly say:

> Yes, I have done.

or

> Yes, I have finished.

However, 'I am done', 'I'm done', or 'I'm all done' is also generally accepted to mean the same thing. I believe it's more prevalent in US English.

Comment: Would _I have done_ work on its own? I find it is missing the task.
Have you done the shopping? Yes I have. Or Yes I have done the shopping. But not Yes I have done.

Comment: Yes, 'I have done' works, because it's not 'on its own'; it's given context by the question, just like 'Yes, I have' is.

Comment: With "I have done", I would specify the object. "I've done it." Also, "It's done." Whoah...semantic satiation on "done"...

Answer (score 1):

In UK English especially, done is a verb, not an adjective. Saying "I'm done" sits very uncomfortably with me.

Comment: So do I, if we follow VBe, the subject of the sentence is BEING DONE not the task.

Comment: Really? You don't find "It's done!" acceptable? I don't think it's the verb/adjective difference, but the agentive use as opposed to the patient.

Comment: Having said which, I (though UK) do find "I'm done" acceptable.

Comment: @Colin Because of Americanisation, I bet. Saying "It is done" (as an adjective) sounds archaic to me. Like something out of a 30's film about Moses.

Comment: "Any progress on that program?" "It's done!" sounds fine to me.

Comment: @Collin, It's done could mean the programme is completed or finish, it's different from I am done.

Comment: Well, the most British papers in the world, "The Times" and "the Sunday Times", have about 160 occurrences of the expression "I'm done", e.g. "But truly, where Harry’s story is concerned, I’m done." (an interview with J.K. Rowling, 2012), or "He will be heading for Heathrow and home as soon as I’ m done" (2006).

Comment: Of course, I'm not suggesting that "I'm done" (in the sense of "finished doing something") has always been common in British English.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, "I have done" is perfectly alright. But if someone is asking after whether you're completed with a task it may be more direct just to reply "I have finished (it)."

Answer (score 0):

"I have finished."

"I am done" means you are a cake that is done.  You're cooked.  If you have finished a task or a job, you should say, "I have finished", or "I'm through".

Comment: *I have finished* - agreed, that makes perfect sense. But *I'm through*? You're through what, a tunnel? I know that's a popular American expression but if you think about it, it doesn't make sense, it's an unfinished sentence. Ironically, it's a sentence which isn't finished/done/whatever!

Answer (score -2):

Silliness, regardless what Oxford and Cambridge argue.

"I have done x" represents a task/project finished in past tense, whereas "I am done" expresses one is finished a task/project in the present tense without further explaination (if one were dead, they could not tell you). But "I finished" means one has completed a task/project without expression, too.

"I finished" is more American/Canadian, while "I have finished" is used by the Brits.