# Is the sentence "We're done" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I'm done or I've done](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10423/im-done-or-ive-done)

When the class is over, our lecturer always says "OK, we're done." Is this sentence grammatically correct? Isn't it a passive form, which simply means we are done by sth./somebody? Can we use "we've done" instead in this case?

Comment: *We've done* is the indicative past perfect of *We do*. Used in this way it must be transitive, so you can say, *We've done it!*, which indicates you achieved something more extraordinary than making it all the way through a single lecture. Anyway, *We did it!* is more common than *We've done it!*. Save it for when you graduate.

Comment: I am not sure that this question is actually a duplicate. In the other question, the sense was that a task had been completed; whereas in this question, the sense is that the doers will do no more (which may or may not be because the task has been completed). In the other question, you could say that the construction "we're done" were awkward and American; but, in this question, that's less clear, isn't it? You might consider unmarking this one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. *Done* here means *finished* and has been used with this meaning since the 14th century, and no one batted an eyelid till 1917. It has been used by Dickens and Mark Twain amongst others, not to mention in the proverb:

Man's work lasts till set of sun, woman's work is never done.

See MWDEU - http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&pg=PA361

Comment: Should have shown the grammatical parsing for completeness. Perhaps you could edit your answer suitably. Also, gives an impression that it is somehow incorrect. What happened in 1917?!

Comment: Hey, I'm just a humble EFL teacher; I don't 'do' parsing.  But I did miss the bit about it not being passive. In any case, Barrie England and Irene have filled in all the details, so there's not much point in me adding anything now. As for 1917, it's all in the MWDEU link. OK, I'm done now.

Comment: Hope you up voted both of them, then. :)

Comment: Have done now. Thanks for the reminder; I'm still new at this game. :)

Comment: Something got missed out there. You probably had a point:  perhaps the 1917 reference was left in the air somewhat, and maybe I should have added a bit more detail. However, in my experience with foreign learners, if you tell them what something means, they usually get the idea pretty quickly. What they don't generally want are lengthy grammatical explanations; that's the best way to turn them off. :)

Comment: *The work* is never done, but *we* are? Have you not conflated objects here? Review the question.

Answer (score 12):

**Done** here isn't treated as a verb, but as an adjective. According to OALD:

**done** (adjective)

1 finished; completed

*When you're done, perhaps I can say something.*

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is grammatical, no, it isn’t passive and no, you can’t say **We've done* instead. *Done* is an adjective meaning *finished* and the sentence is on the pattern Subject (*We*) – Verb (*‘re*) – Complement (*done*). (An alternative reading is to see the verb *to be done* as meaning *to have done*, *to have finished*, even though **We've done* is not actually possible in the context you describe.)

Answer (score 2):

The *'re* part is in place of the verb *are* (Which is the conjugated form for *we* of the verb *to be*), and *we* is the subject; *done* is an adjective meaning "complete, or "finished." So this statement is grammatically correct. We've done has a completely different meaning. The 've part is a conjunction of the verb to have and we. We've done is to say we have done, and we're done is the same as we are done. In this case it would only make sense to say we are done, so the professor is correct.