# "I'm done" (reprised)

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, expressions, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Whether our work be finished, daylight is fading. *We're done.*

Is this wrong? Is it too American? If so, how or why, please?

Would you suggest a concise, well-written alternative to "We're done"?

**A NOTE REGARDING WHETHER THIS QUESTION IS A DUPLICATE**

At a casual glance, my question looks like a duplicate. However, I do not believe that it actually is. I do not mean it to be a duplicate, at any rate.

A question almost like mine has been asked at least twice. However, [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/10423/25823) implies that the work had been finished, which is explicitly not what I imply here; and, perplexingly, [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/52901/25823) *asks* what I have asked, but then *accepts* an answer which (as far as I understand) answers a different question.

So, years later, I think that we have room for another go at this.

(If I am technically mistaken, if my question actually is indeed a duplicate, then would you help me to edit it so that it is not? The point is that the answer I seek does not yet, as far as I know, exist on this site; and that it will probably never exist until the question is more precisely put, as I have tried to do here. Thanks.)

Comment: Perhaps we need a tag `too-american`?

Comment: @Drew: Thanks; good tag. My audience includes Englishmen who find Americanisms irritating, but with whom I (an American) otherwise get along well. If I were going to irritate them, I should at least like to be aware that I were irritating them, so that I could choose to do it a-purpose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not *wrong*, but most casual AmE speakers would not use the subjunctive mood (even though it is correct). I happen to like it, and I don't mind sounding affected now and then. Much more "common" would be something like:

> Whether or not our work is finished, daylight is fading. We're done.
> Whether our work is finished or not, daylight is fading. We're done.

Even in the original example, I think the "Whether or not" construction *sounds* better, technically superior *vel non*.

Comment: I like your answer. It actually answers a different question than I had meant to ask, but is most informative to me. "Sounding affected now and then?" Yes, that's about right. Am guilty as charged.

Comment: Please leave your answer. It's helpful. However, for information, I have now edited my question to sharpen it, making clearer what I was asking.

Comment: AmE uses "done" and "finished" synonymously here. In your example, "done" sounds better because you have already used finished; but "Whether or not our work is done, daylight is fading. We're finished" sounds just as good.

I can't speak to other dialects.

Comment: You write, "this question implies that the work had been finished, which is **explicitly not** what I imply here." So perhaps, "Whether our work be finished, daylight is fading.  ***"Let's go grab a beer."*** :-)