# "I was gone" vs "I had gone"

Tags: tenses

What is the difference between the following two statements.

> By the time you sent me the email, I was gone.
>
> By the time you sent me the email, I had gone.

Both of them clearly expresses what had already happened.

Comment: "I was gone home" is ungrammatical

Comment: Why would people use it then?

Comment: An English speaker wouldn't.

Comment: @simchona here are some links: http://gregfallis.com/2011/09/04/a-small-drama/ http://www.thoughtsandramblings.com/?p=1986

Comment: I don't see the sentence anywhere

Comment: "But by the time I got there, he was gone."

Comment: that's not what you posted in your question.

Comment: Start by reading ["I'm done" or "I've done"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10423/im-done-or-ive-done).

Comment: I don't know if this question made any more sense in earlier versions, but I can't see what it's asking now. Nor do I see much connection between the question title the question text, and any of the current answers. So I'm voting to close as "not a real question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there’s a difference between the sentences in your edited question, I would say that ‘I was gone’ emphasises the state of having gone and that ‘I had gone' emphasises the act of going.

Comment: "Gone" happened before the email was sent. Then why both of them are possible? We say we use past perfect for actions happened before another action in the past.

Comment: @Noah: In 'I was gone', 'gone' has the role of an adjective.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But 'was' is still simple past. How could we use it in this case? Shouldn't it be in past perfect?

Comment: @Noah: Both are possible, depending on whether the speaker wants to emphasise the action or the state.

Comment: @Noah, *He was gone* is the state that you found when you arrived home, hence the simple past of the verb *to be* + adjective. *He had gone* is the past perfect of the verb *to go* indicating that the going occurred before the sending. You could also use the past perfect of the verb *to be*, as in: *By the time you sent me the email, I had been gone for twenty minutes* to emphasise that the state began sometime before the sending of the email.

Answer (score 4):

Your sentences in fact contain two different verbs: *to go* and *to be gone*. The verb *to go* can be postmodified as in *go home, go shopping, go to the beach*, etc. But the verb *to be gone* (which has the meaning of *disappear* or *not be there any more*) cannot. So *he was gone home* is ungrammatical.

Comment: Technically, the predicate is _gone_, and it's not a verb; predicate adjectives generate a verb _be_; but you're on the right track. It's a different predicate, with different syntax.

Comment: Changed the question a little bit. Could you elaborate on what the difference between the simple past and past perfect is in this context.

Comment: They're not the same predicate -- as we both just said -- so any difference in tense is irrelevant. If you have examples differing **only** in tense, it's worth answering that question; otherwise, not.

Comment: @John Lawler, you're right. It would have been more accurate to say that the two verbs in question here are *be* and *go*.

Comment: Yeah, they're the tense carriers, hence the verbs. But the predicate is the meaningful part, and _be_ is as automatic and meaningless as the _It_ in _It's raining_. As a semanticist, I go for the predicate first, and let the verbs fall where they may.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence:

> By the time you sent me the email, I was gone home.

is grammatically incorrect. In English, you can say either "I was gone" or "I was home" but not "I was gone home". This is because the verb *was* followed by either *home* or *gone* represents the place where the speaker is. That is, the speaker *was somewhere*. To say *was gone home* incorrectly uses *was*.

The second sentence is in correct simple past perfect form, and is grammatical.

Comment: Okay when we change it to : By the time you sent me the email, I was home. What will be the difference between this and the past perfect form?